# does ngOnChanges updates input properties?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular , just a question on `ngOnChanges`. I know `ngOnChanges()` method takes one parameter(contains SimpleChange from from "@angular/core) that we can retrieve latest change value as:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, SimpleChange } from "@angular/core";
...
@Input("pa-attr")
bgClass: string;


ngOnChanges(changes: { [property: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    let change = changes["bgClass"];
    console.log(change.currentValue);
}
```

but does `ngOnChanges` actually updates input property `bgClass`? or it just retrieve latest change value and that's it?

Answer (score 2):

ngOnChanges is a hook, which called when a value, defined by decorator @Input will be updated. And inside of ngOnChanges you can already read actual value from this.{YOUR_INPUT_NAME}

Official doc - https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges & https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

You don't need ngOnChanges to update your values defined by @Input, they will be updated by parent component of your component. ngOnChanges just allows you to detect changes and perform some of your logic using updated data if you need it.

Comment: so ngOnChanges doesn't update input property  `bgClass` ? and technically speaking, `bgClass` is stale?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. bgClass will be updated when the parent component will pass a new value to your child component (which is your example). State is very general term, but I think you can call it state of component. You need ngOnChanges to implement some custom logic, when the change will happen. For example, you can do a http request, or process new received data somehow.

Comment: so what do you mean by  the parent component and what's child component? I

Comment: You can read about it here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction, there is nice example in section "Pass data from parent to child with input binding"

Answer (score 0):

**ngOnChanges** is a life cycle hook in case of input()  that called when Reference Changes .

Here to Keep The Point Of That Simple Data Type are immutable so everytime you change the value reference gets updated and ngOnchanges is called and It Compares

but In case of Object and Complex Data type Angular Does a Shallow Comparison  it does not check for EVery value of deep level so in spite of changing the input value in parent it does not call **ngOnChanges** of Child

---

During change detection, when Angular checks components' input properties for change, it uses (essentially) === for dirty checking. For arrays, this means the array references (only) are dirty checked. Since the rawLapsData array reference isn't changing, ngOnChanges() will not be called.

I can think of two possible solutions:

Implement ngDoCheck() and perform your own change detection logic to determine if the array contents have changed. (The Lifecycle Hooks doc has an example.)

Assign a new array to rawLapsData whenever you make any changes to the array contents. Then ngOnChanges() will be called because the array (reference) will appear as a change.

In your answer, you came up with another solution.

Repeating some comments here on the OP:

> I still don't see how laps can pick up on the change (surely it must be using something equivalent to ngOnChanges() itself?) while map can't.

- In the laps component your code/template loops over each entry in the lapsData array, and displays the contents, so there are Angular bindings on each piece of data that is displayed.
- Even when Angular doesn't detect any changes to a component's input properties (using === checking), it still (by default) dirty checks all of the template bindings. When any of those change, Angular will update the DOM. That's what you are seeing.
- The maps component likely doesn't have any bindings in its template to its lapsData input property, right? That would explain the difference.
  Note that lapsData in both components and rawLapsData in the parent component all point to the same/one array. So even though Angular doesn't notice any (reference) changes to the lapsData input properties, the components "get"/see any array contents changes because they all share/reference that one array. We don't need Angular to propagate these changes, like we would with a primitive type (string, number, boolean). But with a primitive type, any change to the value would always trigger ngOnChanges() – which is something you exploit in your answer/solution.

As you probably figured out by now object input properties have the same behavior as array input properties.